# pyTenable REST API script failing due to login issue

Tags: python-3.x, rest

Does anyone know why pyTenable would fail with this error message if I'm able to log into the WebUI with the same account?

```
tenable.errors.APIError: None:403 {"type":"regular","response":[],"error_code":161,"error_msg":"Invalid login credentials.\n","warnings":[],"timestamp":1578682854}
```

I even asked Tenable community and they didn't seem to know

Comment: I know this question is a bit old but if you still have your code that you're using to try and login to the API it would help for you to post it. I've been working with this library quite a bit and may be able to help you out more if I see it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I was able to somehow resolve the issue and I can't remember how I did it.